# Scan from printer using node js

Tags: node.js, cmd

How can I use nodejs to tell the printer(& scanner) to start scanning, I tried to use `exec = require('child_process').exec`  to execute some command prompt, but i don't how to tell scanner to start scanning, I will accept command prompt answer.